# how I can solve this problem "The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency "

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a problem my application was working fine but suddenly when I tried run it its not working anymore and my app not opening it show this

```
    The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\asus\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bc211ce031ad45b6bd82c549766d988a\jetified-startup-runtime-1.1.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

how I can solve this ?? and run my app again and why it show this message ??

update : I tried to fix it but it show me this now

```
Duplicate class org.joda.time.Chronology found in modules jetified-joda-time-2.10-no-tzdb.14-no-tzdb (joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14) and jetified-joda-time-2.10.14 (joda-time:joda-time:2.10.14)
```

Answer (score 0):

check in your build.gradle(app level)

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
         minSdk 22
        targetSdk 32
        }
     }
```